# Round/smooth PCB traces or angular traces?

Tags: pcb-design, trace

I was looking at my LAN8720 module because I tried to build one myself. I realised that the traces on the PCB have mostly round edges/are really smooth while other PCB layouts I see have angular/edgy edges.

Should I make my traces also smooth or does it not matter?

Comment: What pcbs are you referring to?
Firstly, what does the manufacturer of the LAN8720 suggest? Do they have a demo board or pcb layout? What layout guidance do they give?
The debate between curved and sharp turns on pcb traces has long been debated. A quick Google should yield some resources. Last one I read was from Altium. The result - no difference. I'd suggest you do some research for your own edification.

Comment: I do read the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/00002165b.pdf) but it basicly doesnt say anything at all about layout design. I found an eval board from the same company and they have "normal" lines. So I guess as Neil said it is aesthetics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For most circuits, it's a matter of aesthetics.

For microwave circuits, it can make a very small difference to line impedance and losses. For very high voltage circuits, corona on sharp points might be an issue.